# Get name of folders in zip files - Python

Tags: python, directory, zip

I have been searching the whole stackoverflow to get an idea on how to extract only names of subfolders from a zip file path.

I tried using tkinter to get the zip path:

```
Import os
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
from zipfile import ZipFile

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Select file", filetypes=[("zip", "*.zip")])
```

And used the ZipFile and namelist to hopefully get the names of all subfolders.

```
with ZipFile(root.filename, 'r') as f:
    names = f.namelist()
```

However, I get that:

```
['CS10/', 'CS10/.DS_Store', '__MACOSX/', '__MACOSX/CS10/', '__MACOSX/CS10/._.DS_Store', etc........
```

I want to know if there is a way to just get the folder name which is in this case CS10 and so on.

Example: If I have 3 folders named: "Apple" "Orange" "Pear" in a zip file path(Users/Kiona/fruits.zip), I want to print `['Apple','Orange','Pear']`.

Comment: Just iterate over them split on `/` and take only the first string (as long as there are more than one). To exclude the '__MACOSX' directory simply define a list of names that you will exclude from your results and a check to ensure they are not included in the results.

Comment: I am a little confused by your question. A zip file can contain any number of directories and files, and may have an arbitrary layout within it. `namelist()` just returns the full path within the archive of every directory and file it contains. What folder name are you trying to determine and on what basis?

Comment: Thanks @Paul Rooney, I want it so that all platform and all kind of folders can be used for my code though, I was trying to just keep the one that end with "/" and doesn't contain "__" but I don't know if I use another platform (eg. Windows) it will drop some that I need.

Comment: Yeah if for some reason you expect to be OSX hidden file cruft in the archive you'll have to ignore that explicitly.

Comment: Yes you may also look to exclude the files based on a `__` prefix or by hidden status. It will be tricky to provide a bulletproof solution for detecting the files you don't want, you will have to experiment to find a solution that meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you @Iguananaut for your reply. I updated my question, hopefully it's a bit more understandable.

Comment: @kindall, thank you for your explanation. Helped a lot

Comment: @Paul Rooney, thanks for your response. I will dig more into it !

Comment: The question is do you mean top-level folders (i.e. without any other path components in front of them) or the nested folders of any depth? In any case anything ending with *just* `/` is a folder name. The archive contents are the same on any platform so there's nothing to be concerned with about that.

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tested this, but the following might be what you're looking for:

```
with ZipFile(root.filename, 'r') as f:
    names = [info.filename for info in f.infolist() if info.is_dir()]
```

For reference, look at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist and https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.is_dir

Comment: Looks like `is_dir` was added in Python 3.6, but under the hood all it's doing is checking if the filename ends in a '/'